# Getting data under or above a line

Tags: text-processing, grep

This is my file:

```
print energy 1 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol

print energy 2 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 1.682997967326E+05 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 1.682997967326E+05 kJ/mol
```

I need the numbers, but the only way I know which one for me is the `print` line. So far, I have used this command to work it out:

```
tail -16 file.txt | head -1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

But this way is not good I believe. You have to rely on the line number. If the data is in the middle of thousand lines, you are lost. Do you know any better choice for this?

Comment: so in a thousands of lines, print appears for only two times. Am i correct?

Comment: No, it can appear many times.

Comment: it's unclear for me. Did you want to get all the numbers which are just below to the `print` line?

Comment: I just to have the number in 'Global' line

Comment: so want to print the number from the global line which must be below(as second) to the print line.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I think, stephanes answer will work for you.

Comment: Then why you ask me?

Comment: Well, because when I came back, I saw I hadn't replied to your question. If you leave it without saying any word, I think it's rude.

Comment: Which one is rude? You mean [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132516/getting-data-under-or-above-a-line?noredirect=1#comment220114_132632) comment?

Comment: No :)). I means if I stop reply to you, that's rude. So I feel that I need to continue to comment, even when I have the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to print the 6<sup>th</sup> field of the second line after each one containing `print` (guessing), you can use either:

```
awk '/print/{if (getline > 0 && getline > 0) print $6}'
```

Or:

```
awk '!--n {print $6}; /print/ {n=2}'
```

If you want the but-last field in the first line containing `Global` that occurs after the first occurrence of `print energy 1 end`, that would be:

```
awk '/print energy 1 end/{found=1}; found && /Global/ {print $(NF-1); exit}'
```

To print data from lines above the match, you'll need to record data first and then print the recorded data upon the match. For instance to print the 6th field from the line before the first one that contains `print`:

```
awk '/print/{print recorded;exit};{recorded=$6}'
```

Comment: The last one is what I need. What if I need the data above that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With your sample data, here is a `GNU grep` solution:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<== ).+? ' file
1.635393034217E+05 
1.635393034217E+05 
1.682997967326E+05 
1.682997967326E+05
```

Comment: This only works for the sample data, my real file is more complicate than that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cut as well:

```
cut -d "=" -f2 file
```

And if you don't want the "kJ/mol" then pipe with awk:

```
cut -d "=" -f2 file | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: This only works for the sample data, my real file is more complicate than that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed all the print statements are separated by a blank line and also i assumed that you want to print the 6th field of the second line after each one containing print.

```
$ cat ccc
print energy 1 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol

print energy 2 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 1.682997967326E+05 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 1.682997967326E+05 kJ/mol

Read energy 3 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 1.635393034217E+05 kJ/mol


$ awk -v RS='\n\n' '/print/{gsub (/\n/,""); {print $18}}' ccc
1.635393034217E+05
1.682997967326E+05
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the purpose of duplicate the energy 1?

Comment: I don't even get your question.

Comment: Which one? The one I initially ask or the one on the comment above? And what point you don't get it?

Comment: is this "I assumed all the print statements are separated by a blank line and also i assumed that you want to print the 6th field of the second line after each one containing print." assumption  correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Oh I get it, did you just use the old data from `1` for the example, the data in `3` was something added to be looked like a real file?